# Как в VS Code сделать отступы по умолчанию 2?

Tags: visual-studio-code, отступы

Как в vs code поставить отступы в файлах не 4 а 2? Знаю, что можно изменить в нижней строке VS Code. Но это нужно изменять в каждом файле, а так не удобно. Как поставить по умолчанию 2 отступа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите в настройки и введите в поиск `editor.tabSize`, выставите нужное вам значение.
А так же вы можете перейти сюда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это откроет `settings.json`, в нем вы можете настроить размер отступа для определенного языка, допустим так мы можем указать для `html` файлов размер отступа `3`:

```json
{
  "[html]":
  {
    "editor.tabSize": 3
  }
}
```